# Django form field feed with javascript produced list

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm learning Django through a recipe posting website, in the recipe form I want to pass an ingredient list that is created with a java script function on the fly. I have two buttons, one to create the list, and the final submit button when the recipe form is ready.  The problem is that every time the ingredients "adding ingredient button" is clicked,  the form is submitted, since it is not valid it resets the whole form. How can I integrate the java script without submitting the form?

I've tried many solutions that I've seen everywhere to no avail, so any help is welcome.

Model.

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    """Represents the whole recipe description"""
    recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, help_text='Enter a brief description of the recipe')
    ingredients = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='enter all the ingredients with quantities')
    cooking_time = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    preparation = models.TextField(max_length=3000, help_text='Enter the steps to prepare the recipe')
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

script.

```js
function checkdata(){
        //Create references to the input elements we wish to validate
        var ingredient = document.getElementById("ingredient");
        var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");

        //Check if username field is empty
        if(ingredient.value == ""){
                alert("Please enter the ingredient");
                ingredient.focus();
                return false;
        }
        //Check if email field is empty
        if(quantity.value == ""){
                alert("Please enter the quantity");
                quantity.focus();
                return false;
        }
        //If all is well return true.
        else{ ingList();}
    }


function ingList(){
    var values = [ingredient.value, quantity.value];
    let data =[];
    data.push(values);
    var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerText = data;
        list.appendChild(li);
        const list = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('myList').value=list);
    document.getElementById("ingredient").value = "";
    document.getElementById("quantity").value = "";
    return false
    }
```

html.

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'Ingredients.js' %}"></script>
<h3><a href="{% url 'my_page' %}">BACK</a></h3>
<body>
<p>{{ user }} please fill up the form.</p>
<br>
<form action="{% url 'new_recipe' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <label for="recipe_name">Recipe Name: </label>
            <input id="recipe_name" type="text" name="recipe_name" value="{{ form.recipe_name }}">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <label for="description">Description: </label>
            <textarea id="description" name="description" value="{{ form.description }}"></textarea>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <label for="cooking_time">Cooking Time: </label>
            <input id="cooking_time" type="text" name="cooking_time" value="{{ form.cooking_time }}">
        </div>
        <br>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Enter Ingredients</legend>
            <label for="ingredient">Ingredient name :</label>
            <input type="text" id="ingredient" name="ingredient">
            <span>
            <label for="quantity">Enter the quantity:</label>
            <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity"></span><br><br>
            <button id="add" type="button" onclick="checkdata()" value="ingredients">Add Ingredient</button>
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <div>
            <label for="ingredients">Ingredients: </label>
            <textarea id="myList"></textarea>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <label for="preparation">Preparation: </label>
            <input id="preparation" type="text" name="preparation" value="{{ preparation }}">
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="Add Recipe">Add Recipe</button>
</form>
</body>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. **Missing `type` attribute**.
   You have not specified the type attribute on the button that adds ingredients. This defaults to `type="submit"` since it is inside a form element. To disable this behaviour, change it to:

```html
<button type="button"... ">Add Ingredient</button>
```

2. **Misplaced event listener**
   You have placed a `submit` event listener on the `fieldset` element, but that element does emit that event. Only `<button type="submit">` and  do.
   If you want to prevent immediate submission of the form when the submit button is clicked, attach the event listener on the submit button:

```html
<input type="submit" value="Add Recipe" onsubmit="checkdata(e) { e.preventDefault();}>
```

However, the script for `onsubmit` attribute doesn't make sense. Are you trying to call a function you defined somewhere? If yes, that's not how you do it. If no, are you trying to define a JavaScript function? If yes, that's not a place to do it.

Please share your JavaScript code you're using to populate the ingredient list so I can update the answer with a solution.

Also, unless you just want to practice with JavaScript, you don't need JavaScript for recipe-adding app, you can simply use a `ManyToMany` field for recipe's ingredients.

Comment: McPherson, thanks for your observations, for some reason I repeated the models code instead of copying the <script> which I already updated. So I made the mistake placing onsubmit instead of onclick, and the button type among other errors. I will work on it and see how it goes. Any other advice is welcome. Thanks.